# How can I store a tree structure in JPA?

Tags: jpa

I need to store a large amount of nodes with many-to-many relationship to eachother (through parents/childrens). How can I do that in JPA?

I know I can use @ManyToMany on my parents/childrens list but then JPA will load the all parents and their parents and so on right? Is there any way I can do it and only load the parents or children one step away?

The non-working code I have now (the Node.java):

```
public String name;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "NodeParent")
public List<Node> parents;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "NodeChilds")
public List<Node> childrens;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this JPA has the concept op `lazy loading`.

While iterating over the collection when still within the persistence context, every time you reference a not previously loaded entity, it will be loaded on demand.

Additionally, if you know up-front which entities you need (how deep you want the tree to be fetched) you can write a projection query (JPQL) using the `fetch join` operator.

Finally, a hibernate specific solution that might be included in JPA 2.1 are so-called `fetch profiles`. See [Fetch profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e3524) and [Fetch Profiles in Hibernate 3.5](http://rossenstoyanchev.org/blog/2009/09/02/fetch-profiles-in-hibernate-35/).